# What rule governs the varying nikkud in words מִשְׁתֶּה and מִשְׁתֵּה?

Tags: grammar-dikduk, torah-reading, megillat-esther, vowels-nekudot

What rule governs the varying nikkud in words מִשְׁתֶּה and מִשְׁתֵּה in Megillas Ester? In Ashkenazi pronunciation this makes a difference because the first is read as "Mishte" and the second is read as "MishteY."

Comment: Please bring the exact Psukim, we don't know what you refer to

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When משתה is in [construct state](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Construct_state) it has a *tzere* instead of a *segol* and would mean "drinking-party of" instead of just "drinking-party".

Comment: I believe this is the case for all masculine *miktal* nouns whose last radical is a ה (like מענה, מעשה, מחנה).