# What is the explanation of spelling the same word with a Patach instead of a Sh'va in Megillat Esther?

Tags: grammar-dikduk, torah-reading, megillat-esther, vowels-nekudot, spelling-variants

In Megillat Esther, why is the word "maidens" spelled with a sh'va under the first letter (נְעָרוֹת) in verses 2:2, 2:8, 2:9, but with a patach (נַעֲרוֹת) in verse 4:4?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When נערות is in [construct state](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Construct_state) it has a *patach* instead of a *sh'va* and would mean "maidens of" instead of just "maidens".

Comment: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/97714/759

Answer (score 0):

The instances in chapter 2 are the regular noun, meaning “maidens”.

In chapter 4, the word is in the construct state, meaning “maidens of”. This is denoted by the alternative vowelization.